# (non-static method Change(String,String,String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, methods

I've searched, but didn't understand how to incorporate previous answers with my own code. I have an assigment to create a draft of a program for the schools "bank/scholarship"-system. Here we need to create a lot of different methods, that should be called instead of just doing the change directly.

The thing is, I keep getting the error-message in the topic along with a few others, and I don't know how to fix it. I would really appreciate if someone could explain for me how and why to change one of my methods, then I assume I will be able to rewrite all the others myself. Here is my code so far:

class Address

```
public class Address {

public String street, zip, post;

public Address (String street, String zip, String post) {

    this.street = street;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.post = post;
}

// these are setters (mutators)
public void setStreet (String street) {
    this.street = street; }

public void setZip (String zip) {
    this.zip = zip; }

public void setPost (String post) {
    this.post = post; }

// these are getters
public String getStreet () {
    return this.street; }

public String getZip () {
    return zip; }

public String getPost () {
    return post; }

// methods
//public Address Change(Address newAddress) {
//return newAddress;
//}

// output
public String toString() {
    return (street + ", " + zip + ", "+ post); }

}
```

class Customer

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Customer {

DecimalFormat twoD = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
Address address = new Address("Vik ", "6393 ", "Tomrefjord");

public String name, campus, newCampus, newAddress;
public double loan, increase,decrease,regMaster;
public boolean finished;

public Customer (String name,Address address, String campus, double loan, boolean finished) {
    this.name = name;
    this.campus = campus;
    this.loan = loan;
    this.address = address;
    this.finished = finished;
}

// these are setters
public void setName (String name) {
    this.name = name; }

public void setCampus (String campus) {
    this.campus = campus; }

public void setLoan (double loan) {
    this.loan = loan; }

public void setFinished (boolean finished) {
    this.finished = finished; }

// these are getters
public String getName () {
    return name; }

public String getCampus () {
    return campus; }

public double getLoan () {
    return loan; }

// methods
public void RegMaster () {
this.loan = loan * 0.90;}

//public void changeAddress (Address newAddress) {
//Address.Change(newAddress); }

public double decreaseLoan (double currentBalance, double decrease) {
currentBalance = currentBalance - decrease;
return currentBalance; }

public double getNewLoan (double currentBalance, double newLoan) {
    newLoan = currentBalance + newLoan;
    return newLoan; }

public String getNewCampus (String newCampus) {
    campus = newCampus;
    return campus; }    

public static boolean Ended () {
    return  true; } 

// output
public String toString() {
        return (name + "\t\n" + address + "\t\n" + campus + "\t\n" + twoD.format(loan) + "\t\n" + finished); }






}
```

class TestCustomer

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCustomer {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    String student, school, answer, street, zip, post;
    double balance, master;
    boolean finished = false;
    double done = 0; //this is for the loop

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // a new student receives a loan
    System.out.println("Write your name");
    student = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your street name and number");
    street = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your zip code?");
    zip = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your post area?");
    post = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Where do you study?");
    school = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input your current loan");
    balance = scan.nextDouble();

    Address residence = new Address(street, zip, post);
    Customer customer = new Customer(student, residence, school, balance, finished);
    while(done < 1) { //the variable done will have the value 0 until you are finished.
    // change address
    System.out.println("Do you wish to change your address? (yes/no)");
    answer = scan.nextLine();
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) { //this made it case-insensitive, and now it is not skipping anymore...
        System.out.println("Write your street name and house number");
                street = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Write your zip code");
                zip = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Write your post area");
                post = scan.nextLine();
                //Address newAddress = new Address(street, zip, post);
                //residence = Customer.changeAddress(newAddress);
    }

    // increase the loan
    System.out.println("Do you want to increase your loan? (yes/no)");
    answer = scan.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                System.out.println("How much do you need?");
                double increaseLoan = scan.nextDouble();
                //customer.balance = getNewLoan(customer.balance, moreLoan);
            }

    // decrease the loan
    System.out.println("Do you want to make a downpayment on your loan?");
    answer = scan.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                    System.out.println("How much do you intend to pay?");
                    double downpayment = scan.nextDouble();
                    //customer.balance = decreaseLoan(customer.balance, downpayment);
                }


    // change school
    System.out.println("Do you study at the same school? (yes/no");
    answer = scan.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                System.out.println("Write the name of the new school");
                school = scan.nextLine(); }
                //school.getNewCampus(customer.campus);

    // master check
    System.out.println("Have you finished your master? (yes/no)");
    answer = scan.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                customer.finished = Customer.Ended() ; //this will set finished to true, using the method like intended
                //customer.balance = Customer.RegMaster();      // dont know how to invoke it... me neither -_-
                }
            System.out.println("Are you done? yes/no");
            answer = scan.nextLine();
                        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                    done = 1; } // this adds 1 to the variable done, thus ending the loop.
            }
            // output
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("The data we have so far is:");
            System.out.println(customer);

}}
```

Here are all three of my classes. Some of the functions are commented away, others are just not working properly (the code is also a little extra messy, I was changing back and forth to try to get it working yesterday). Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: what errors are you getting and where?

Comment: Judging from your question title [this](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/anatomy/static.html) may help.

Comment: Where is the "change" function you get error on?

Comment: what are the error you are getting ??

Comment: We are supposed to be able to change the address of the customer, by calling changeAddress in class Customer which then calls Change in class Address and actually makes the change... This should then return it back to the address-variable.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, from you comment then your problem comes from the (helpfully) commented out lines

```
//public void changeAddress (Address newAddress) {
//Address.Change(newAddress); }
```

This is because your `Customer` done not "have an" `Address`, you need an address instance and not a `String`:

```
private Address address;

public Customer (final Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

I have redacted other variables for clarity. Incidentally I would use a [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) rathen than one enormous constructor.
Now that you have an `Address` in your `Customer`:

```
public void changeAddress (Some parameters to change) {
  address.setStuff();
}
```

I would recommend that you read [this link](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/anatomy/static.html) about the difference between `static` and `instance` variables.

Comment: Thank you, that was enlightening! After some work I made it work as intended! :)